# Cost function - vectorized implementation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectorization

I have a problem regarding how to vectorize, more specifically the problem below:

Repeat {
$$\theta_j := \theta_j - \frac{\alpha}{m} \sum\limits_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})x_j^{(i)}$$
}

Vectorized to:

$$\theta := \theta - \frac{\alpha}{m}X^T (g(X\theta)-\vec{y})$$

I can't seem to figure out, how to go from the top equation to the bottom. More specifically why the expression $h_\theta(x^{(i)})$ changes into $g(X\theta)$. Furthermore I assume that the summation and $x_j$ are substituted by $X^T$.

Comment: Do you have information about the indexes? What's the difference between $x^{(i)}$ and $x_j$?

Comment: @SergioAndrade i relates to the specific observation i.e what index the observation has, while j relates to the different variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let H denote the hypothesis matrix,

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\dot{H}_{m \times 1}:=\left(\begin{array}{c}{h_{\theta}\left(x^{1}\right)} \\ {h_{\theta}\left(x^{2}\right)} \\ {\vdots} \\ {h_{\theta}\left(x^{m}\right)}\end{array}\right)=g(X \theta})\end{array}
$$

> Recall that the hypothesis function of a logistic regression is a function of the linear regression (which is $ X\theta $).

Let E denote the error matrix,

$$
E_{m \times 1}:=\left(\begin{array}{c}{e_{1}} \\ {e_{2}} \\ {\vdots} \\ {e_{m}}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}{h_{\theta}\left(x^{1}\right)-y^{1}} \\ {h_{\theta}\left(x^{2}\right)-y^{2}} \\ 
{\vdots} \\
{h_{\theta}\left(x^{m}\right)-y^{m}}\end{array}\right)_{m \times 1}=H-\vec{y}
$$

Let $ \delta $ denote the summation term

$$
\begin{aligned} \delta_{j} &:=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(h_{\theta}\left(x^{(i)}\right)-y^{(i)}\right) x_{j}^{(i)} \\ &=\frac{1}{m}\left(e_{1} x_{j}^{1}+e_{2} x_{j}^{2}+\ldots+e_{m} x_{j}^{m}\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{m} x_{j}^{\top} E \\ \end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c}{\delta:=\left(\begin{array}{c}{\delta_{0}} \\ {\delta_{1}} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\delta_{n}}\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{m} X^{\top} E}\end{array} 
$$

$$
{\theta=\theta-\alpha \delta}
$$
When you expand $ \delta $, you will obtain the second equation. Note that this vectorised form applies for **linear regression** too, as they have the same gradient descent formula with a different hypothesis function. Thus for linear regression, simply substitute $ g(X\theta) $ with $ X\theta $.